# sqlalchemy - Failed to open the referenced table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a newbie to sql and sqlalchemy, what am I doing wrong here? The error occurs at the time of upgrade.

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 134, in upgrade
    _upgrade(directory, revision, sql, tag, x_arg)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 96, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 271, in upgrade
    command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 294, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 490, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 97, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 182, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations/env.py", line 90, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 813, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 561, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/migrations/versions/4985d3e36676_.py", line 21, in upgrade
    op.create_table('Favorites_List',
  File "<string>", line 8, in create_table
  File "<string>", line 3, in create_table
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/ops.py", line 1072, in create_table
    return operations.invoke(op)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 354, in invoke
    return fn(self, operation)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/toimpl.py", line 101, in create_table
    operations.impl.create_table(table)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 277, in create_table
    self._exec(schema.CreateTable(table))
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 146, in _exec
    return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1014, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 72, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1071, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 264, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "/workspace/Star-Wars-Blog-API/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 491, in cmd_query
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 1824 (HY000): Failed to open the referenced table 'Planet'
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE `Favorites_List` (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `USER_ID` INTEGER, 
        `FAV_CHARACTER` INTEGER, 
        `FAV_PLANET` INTEGER, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(`FAV_CHARACTER`) REFERENCES `Character` (id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(`FAV_PLANET`) REFERENCES `Planet` (id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `Userr` (id)
)

]
```

Quick summary of the design;
When user creates account, user info is post in the userr table. Character and Planet tables are going to have the necessary data from the very beginning, it's not something meant to be modified at any point, at least for this project.

Favorites_List table will hold the user id, a fav_char, and a fav_planet.

When a specific existing user, adds a character or planet to favorites a new entry in the Favorites_List table will be created, with the user_id, and the id of either the fav character or fav planet. Aka, one of the columns is meant to be empty for every entry. If I add a fav char, the fav planet field will be empty, and vice versa.

[image]

```py
class Userr(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Userr'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    USER_FNAME = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    USER_LNAME = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    USER_EMAIL = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    USER_PASSWORD = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    USER_FAVORITE_LIST = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Favorites_List.id"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Userr %r>' % self.userrname

class Favorites_List(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Favorites_List'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    USER_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Userr.id'))
    FAV_CHARACTER = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Character.id'))
    FAV_PLANET = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Planet.id'))
    user = db.relationship("Userr", foreign_keys=[USER_ID])
    favoriteChar = db.relationship("Character")
    favoritePlanet = db.relationship("Planet")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Favorites_List %r>' % self.id

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "favorite_character": self.FAV_CHARACTER,
            "favorite_planet": self.FAV_PLANET,
            # do not serialize the password, its a security breach
        }


class Planet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Planet'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    PLANET_NAME = db.Column(db.String(250))
    PLANET_ROT_PERIOD = db.Column(db.Integer)
    PLANET_TRANS_PERIOD = db.Column(db.Integer)
    PLANET_DIAMETER = db.Column(db.Integer)
    PLANET_CLIMATE = db.Column(db.String(250))
    PLANET_GRAVITY = db.Column(db.String(250))
    PLANET_TERRAIN = db.Column(db.String(250))
    PLANET_SURFACE_WATER = db.Column(db.Integer)
    PLANET_POP = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Planet %r>' % self.PLANET_NAME

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "planet_name": self.PLANET_NAME,
            "planet_pop": self.PLANET_POP,
            "planet_terrain": self.PLANET_TERRAIN,
            # do not serialize the password, its a security breach
        }

class Character(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Character'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    CHAR_NAME = db.Column(db.String(250))
    CHAR_SPECIES = db.Column(db.String(250))
    CHAR_GENDER = db.Column(db.String(250))
    CHAR_YOB = db.Column(db.String(250))
    CHAR_HEIGHT = db.Column(db.Integer)
    CHAR_WEIGHT = db.Column(db.Integer)
    CHAR_EYE_COLOR = db.Column(db.String(250))
    CHAR_HAIR_COLOR = db.Column(db.String(250))
    CHAR_SKIN_COLOR = db.Column(db.String(250))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Character %r>' % self.CHAR_NAME

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "species": self.CHAR_SPECIES,
            "name": self.CHAR_NAME,
            "gender": self.CHAR_GENDER
            # do not serialize the password, its a security breach
        }
```

Comment: what error? Don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides it may work correctly on our computers. aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you create table `Planet` before `Favorites_List` ? It may need to put classes in different order - first `Class Planet` next `class Favorites_List`

Comment: Post updated with whole error message. Putting classes in different order did not work. If bad I don't remember, the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: I can create these tables with SQLAlchemy and MySQL Connector, but I can't drop them - `sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Can't sort tables for DROP; an unresolvable foreign key dependency exists between tables: Favorites_List, Userr`.  It's possible that the relationships between your tables are causing your problem.  Also, I would use lower-case names for your tables; having a model and table both named "Planet" is going to confuse readers of your code, even if SQLAlchemy can tell the difference.